# Live streaming from h.264 IP camera to Web browser

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, h.264, ffserver

I want to live stream video from h.264/h.265 IP camera to browser with little to no delay and in decent quality (Full HD). I know there are couple of questions like this one but the answers seem to be either incomplete or outdated. So far I've tried `ffmpeg` and `ffserver` and had some success with them, but there are problems:

When I stream to `mjpg` the quality isn't great, if I use `webm` quality is better but there is significant delay (aprox. 5 seconds), probably due to transcoding from `h264` to `vp9`. How can I improve it? Is it possible to stream `h264` without transcoding it to different format? Are there any better solutions than `ffserver` and `ffmpeg`?

Here is the config I've used for mjpg:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://rtsp_user:Rtsp_pass@192.168.3.83:554/Streaming/Channels/101 -q:v 3 http://localhost:8090/feed3.ffm
```

on ffserver:

```
<feed feed3.ffm>
   file /tmp/feed3.ffm
   filemaxsize 1G
   acl allow 127.0.0.1
</feed>

<Stream cam3.mjpg>
    Feed feed3.ffm
    Format mpjpeg
    VideoCodec mjpeg
    VideoFrameRate 25
    VideoIntraOnly
    VideoBufferSize 8192
    VideoBitRate 8192
    VideoSize 1920x1080
    VideoQMin 5
    VideoQMax 15
    NoAudio
    Strict -1
</Stream>
```

And for webm:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://rtsp_user:Rtsp_pass@192.168.3.83:554/Streaming/Channels/101 -c:v libvpx http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed4.ffm
```

ffserver:

```
<Stream cam4.webm>
   Feed feed4.ffm 
   Format webm
   # Audio settings
   NoAudio
   # Video settings
   VideoCodec libvpx
   VideoSize 720x576           
   VideoFrameRate 25           
   AVOptionVideo qmin 10
   AVOptionVideo qmax 42 
   AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
   PreRoll -1
   StartSendOnKey
   VideoBitRate 400            
</Stream>
```